# what to write in applicationContext.xml in order to get hibernate session in filter

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I need to initialize hibernate session in Filter for spring mvc, I know I need to add ContextListner in web.xml but I have no Idea of what to write in applicationContext.xml file.please guide to some tutorial or example ...

**detailed explaination:** I need to prepopulate my form using spring form tag, for that I need HibernateSession open in jsp lifecycle execution. I created a HibernateSessionFilter to enable hibernate session in jsp. Now again for that I need to initialize my hibernate session. see the

> sf = //don't know what to write ;

in code below. I dont know how I can get hibernate sessionFactory there. I know it can be done via applicationContext.xml but can't get to the exact configuration needed.

**edit1*********

now again back to same exception where I started:

```
 org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'firstname' of bean class [net.viralpatel.contact.form.Contact_$$_javassist_0]: Getter for property 'firstname' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:845)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:721)
at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:120)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_005fedit_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(contact_005fedit_jsp.java:255)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_005fedit_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(contact_005fedit_jsp.java:177)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_005fedit_jsp._jspService(contact_005fedit_jsp.java:126)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:761)
        ... 55 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
        at net.viralpatel.contact.form.Contact_$$_javassist_0.getFirstname(Contact_$$_javassist_0.java)
        ... 60 more
Sep 16, 2012 4:36:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
        at net.viralpatel.contact.form.Contact_$$_javassist_0.getFirstname(Contact_$$_javassist_0.java)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:761)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:721)
        at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
        at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:219)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:120)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_005fedit_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(contact_005fedit_jsp.java:255)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_005fedit_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(contact_005fedit_jsp.java:177)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.contact_005fedit_jsp._jspService(contact_005fedit_jsp.java:126)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Sep 16, 2012 4:36:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/Spring3HibernateMaven] threw exception [org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'firstname' of bean class [net.viralpatel.contact.form.Contact_$$_javassist_0]: Getter for property 'firstname' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException] with root cause
```

my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Spring3-Hibernate</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>list.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

my Contact Class:

```
package net.viralpatel.contact.form;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="CONTACTS")
public class Contact {

@Id
@Column(name="ID")
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
private String firstname;

@Column(name="LASTNAME")
private String lastname;

@Column(name="EMAIL")
private String email;

@Column(name="TELEPHONE")
private String telephone;


public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public String getTelephone() {
    return telephone;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
    this.telephone = telephone;
}
public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}
public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}
public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}
public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

My Application filter:

```
private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(HibernateSessionRequestFilter.class);

private SessionFactory sf;

 public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    log.debug("Initializing filter...");
    sf = //don't know what to write ;
}

}
```

My ContactDAO

```
@Repository
public class ContactDAOImpl implements ContactDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void addContact(Contact contact) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(contact);
}

public List<Contact> listContact() {

    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Contact")
            .list();
}

public void removeContact(Integer id) {
    Contact contact = (Contact) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(
            Contact.class, id);
    if (null != contact) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(contact);
    }

}

public Contact editContact(Integer id) {
    Contact contact = (Contact) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(
            Contact.class, id);
    System.out.println("contact: "+contact);
    if (null != contact) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(contact);
    }
    return contact;
}

public Contact getContact(Integer id) {
    Contact contact = (Contact) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(
            Contact.class, id);
    return contact;
}

}
```

Controller render method for edit page:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{contactId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView edit(@PathVariable("contactId") Integer contactId,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    Contact contact = contactService.getContact(contactId);

    Map<String, Object> model = new HashedMap();
    model.put("contact", contact);

    return new ModelAndView("contact_edit", model);
}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/doedit/{contactId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editContact(@PathVariable("contactId") Integer contactId) {

    contactService.editContact(contactId);

    return "redirect:/index";
}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear: You talk about "hibernate session Filter" -- Do you mean `OpenSessionInViewFilter`? But this is already configured!

Comment: check this line , you will get to know what I am talking about       "sf = //don't know what to write" ;

Comment: I have got it, next time reorganize you code a bit, so that the relevant method is on top, so that one can read the code in Stack Overflow without scrolling

Comment: first: does the problem remain after you have remove your filter? second: do you do anything with the hibernate session like closing it?

Comment: yes problem for getters setters not found remains same. for second point can you please check my ContactDAO in edited post

Comment: Looks ok, I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: thanks ..you have given lot of time on this .... will digg more .. thanks again .

Comment: Try to implement a little sample project (from an tutorial) and if this work, then try to copy parts from your real project to that sample project step by step until it does not work anymore. So you may find the cause of the problem.

Comment: I followed this tutorial http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring3-mvc-hibernate-maven-tutorial-eclipse-example/ It works fine for add/delete/list . Their wasn't any implementation for edit, so am trying to implement same.

Comment: I think I haven an idea, could you please post the methods of your @Controller which are used to update the contact

Comment: check the edited post .. I don't know if it is allowed at SO. but if u like to investigate further I can upload my source code, it doesn't contain much and most of that is already posted ...

Comment: The link to the tutorial is enough.

Comment: there must be a second controller method: your controller method `edit(Integer, HttpServletRequest)`  provides only the form for the edit. But there must be a second one that takes the user input and perform the update. -- Do you have such an method? If yes, then please post it.

Comment: Ralph ..yes I have such method, but my problem is I am not able to render the page itself, submitting it is the next part ... check the edited post for editContact method

Comment: My fault (I was thinking in the wrong direction). Could you please upload the complete programm to any sharing plattform so that I can have a look on it.

Comment: check the link http://www.2shared.com/file/5a6-x7C1/Spring3HibernateMaven.html let me know if any issue.

Comment: ManMohan Vyas: see my new answer, now it works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found one major bug in your code and one minor.

The major bug is that you have configured TWO Hibernate Session Factories (this cases the stange exception) on in `applicationContext.xml` (correct) and on in `spring-servlet.xml` (this must be removed). (some more details as comment in the xml)

The updated `spring-servlet.xml`

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.viralpatel.contact" />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<!--
Already defined in the inner spring context, you do not need it twice

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
-->

<!--
ONLY one session factory per application!!
You have configured them already in applicationContext.xml

Spring mvc application have two spring contexts, an other and an inner context.
The inner context is created by ContextLoaderListener and in your case it is described in applicationContext.xml.
The outer context is created by DispatcherServelet and in your case it is described in spring-servlet.xml.

Filters can access only the inner context, therefore the OpenSessionInViewFilter requires that the inner context contain all the hibernate stuff
The outer context can beans access the inner context.
The outer context has access to all the web stuff (not like the inner context) therefore the @Controller Beans can be only instanceated in the outer context.



    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
-->

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <!-- JSR-303 support will be detected on classpath and enabled automatically -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The minor bug ins in your `contact_edit.jsp`

Instead of `<form:form method="post" action="add.html" commandName="contact">` use:

```
<c:url var="updateUrl" value="/doedit/${contact.id}"/>
<form:form method="post" action="${updateUrl}" commandName="contact">
```

And after this modification of your `editContact` I was able to modify the first name

```
/**
 * This is only prove that it works.
 * You should not update the contact directly in the controller (this is only a shortcut in for the example).
 * If you load and update the contact in an method that is @Transactional, than you can remove the @Transactional from this
 * controller method.
 */
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "/doedit/{contactId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editContact(@PathVariable("contactId") final Integer contactId, final Contact editedContact) {

  //contactService.editContact(contactId);

    Contact contact = contactService.getContact(contactId);
    contact.setFirstname(editedContact.getFirstname()); //only first name for the example

    return "redirect:/index";
}
```

Comment: may be I failed to frame it properly, can you please check my edited post

Comment: can you please give an example about getting HibernateSession from applicationContext.xml

Comment: sorry ralph but totally messed up , all I want is to pre-populate my spring form , after doing everything as you said It is back with the starting error. where it cannot find hibernae session. firstname getters and setters are already at right place.

Comment: Ralph .. ossum dedication friend ... thanks a lot ..awarding you a bounty of 50 points ...sorry I need to wait extra 24 hours for the bounty ..you will recieve it tomorrow